# Cannot save Spark dataframe to Google Cloud Storage from PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, google-cloud-storage

I have a Spark dataframe that I'm trying to save to a Google Storage bucket with the line

```
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save('gs://some-test-bucket-delete-me')
```

But Pyspark raises the following exception

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o55.save.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found
```

**What I've tried:**

The typical solutions to this exception is to make sure that the environmental variable `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` to point at the `gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar` file, which it does. I've tried using the Hadoop version 1 as well as version 2 jars incase that was the problem. I've  tried explicitly pointing at it within Jupyter notebook with

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/home/****/hadoop-2.8.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/gcs-connector-latest-hadoop1.jar")
```

to no avail.

If I try `hadoop fs -ls gs://gs://some-test-bucket-delete-me` from bash the command returns perfectly, which is supposed to indicate that that the Google Cloud Storage connect works but for some reason I can't seem to get this functionality to work in PySpark.

Things that may be important:

Spark Version 2.2.0

Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

I'm running PySpark locally

Answer (score 1):

You should run `gcloud init` first

Then try `df.write.csv('gs://some-test-bucket-delete-me/file_name')`